# Maven Authentication failed

Tags: maven

I installed Maven 3.6.3 on my company computer and it runs with jdk 13.0.3. I add a certificate to the java KeyStore and configured the proxy at my settings.xml. But I still can´t get dependencies from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ repository. I can access the site with my browser.

Does somebody has any idea?

**mvn -v:**

```
c:\progs\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin>mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: c:\progs\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 13.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: c:\progs\java\jdk-13.0.2
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

**settings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <localRepository>c:\progs\maven-repository</localRepository>

  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>*****</username>
      <password>*****</password>
      <host>*****</host>
      <port>3128</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
</project>
```

**mvn output:**

```
c:\progs>apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\mvn clean
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------< com.mycompany.app:my-app >----------------------
[INFO] Building my-app 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.800 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-15T09:51:25+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Authentication failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom 401 authenticationrequired -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

I think the proxy settings are correct, when I change them (false password) I get another failure:

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): HTTP proxy server authentication failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom 407 authenticationrequired -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: I installed Maven on an Ubuntu VM in the same network, there works it without adding a certificate. I have no idea, why it doesn´t work on the windows machine.

Comment: i installed a nexus repository server on the ubuntu VM and use it as a proxy now.

Comment: This helped me. With the jar in my maven installation it worked.
https://codepen.io/ugbandula/post/how-to-configure-maven-to-work-with-ntlm-proxies

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. In my case it was not a proxy but a company repository.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Computing target platform for MavenProject: org.company:org.company.editor:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Users\userA\source\proj\bundles\org.company.editor\pom.xml
[INFO] Adding repository https://artifacts.company.org/repository/snapshots/composite/nightly
[ERROR] Failed to resolve target definition C:\Users\userA\source\proj\releng\org.company.target\org.company.target.target: Failed to load p2 metadata repository from locationhttps://artifacts.company.org/repository/snapshots/composite/nightly/: Authentication failed for https://artifacts.company.org/repository/snapshots/composite/nightly. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

The ID might be crucial that maven can find the server credentials
using tycho target definition from eclipse it required to name all locations with an ID

**org.company.target.target:**

```
...
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
        <repository id="<UNIQUE_SERVER_ID>" location="https://artifacts.company.org/repository/branches/release/1.13.2.1/"/>
        <unit id="org.company.preferences.ui.feature.feature.group" version="1.0.0.202108311713"/>
        <unit id="org.company.feature.feature.group" version="1.0.0.202108311713"/>
    </location>
...
```

add the server ID into the maven settings:

**settings.xml**

```
<servers>
<server>
  <id><UNIQUE_SERVER_ID></id>
  <username>userA</username>
  <password><![CDATA[PASSWORD]]></password>
</server>
```

In your case maybe try to put the ID in the repositories tag of your parent pom:

```
<repository>
 <id><UNIQUE_REPO_ID></id>
 <name>repo</name> 
 <releases>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
  <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
 </releases>
<url><REPOSITORY_URL></url>
```